# Aquarium and pond questions that are not about pets

Tags: discussion, on-topic

Before the pets proposal entered private Beta followers of the aquarium proposal were asked to join as all their questions would be on topic here.

There are a few questions about aquariums or ponds I can imagine that are not related to creatures living in that environment. While a question like "[How do I know when I need to replace the charcoal in my aquarium filter?](https://pets.stackexchange.com/q/347/58)" indirectly affects the pets living in the aquarium, there could be questions that are solely about the container or the decoration (maybe even about aquatic dioramas, completely without animals).

As I imagine those question would have been on topic on an aquarium.SE how do we want to treat such questions on pets.SE?

Answer (score 8):

I am going to equate this to effectively managing and caring for a bird's cage or a dog's kennel.  Would we accept questions about managing the living/sleeping quarters for any other pet?  If so, then why should aquariums be any different?

My vote is yes, they should absolutely be on topic

Comment: I absolutely agree. Questions about care, shelter, and the living environments of pets should be squarely on topic here.